# Difference between 'object' ,{} and Object in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Trying to figure out the difference between these 2 types in TypeScript:

`foo: object`

and

`bar: {}`

and
`type: Object` ?

---

**Example:** trying to assign an `object` to the variable that suppose to handle headers information for a request:

```
headers: object;
```

Results in an error:

> Type 'object' is not assignable to '{ [key: string]: string }`.

The same condition passes if using `headers: {}`, which leads to conclusion that `{}` has some slightly less tight requirements.

Comment: I wonder if there is any, because there does not appear to be.

Comment: Under some circumstances TypeScript would trigger an error for one of those. So there might be some.

Comment: Well, they are assignable to each other, so please add any such error cases you are aware of to the question.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

TypeScript has three confusing types: `Object`, `{}` and `object`.

You can assign `null` and `undefined` to all three types if `strictNullChecks` compiler option is disabled otherwise the compile error occurs.

#### Object

Contains stuff (like `toString()`, `hasOwnProperty()`) that is present in all JavaScript objects. Any value (primitive, non-primitive) can be assigned to `Object` type.

#### {}

`{}` is an empty object. It is pretty much the same as `Object` in runtime but different in compile time.  In compile time `{}` doesn't have `Object`'s members and `Object` has more strict behavior (see the @golmschenk's comment).

#### object

`object` [was introduced in TypeScript 2.2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html). It is any **non-primitive type**. You can't assign to it any primitive type like `bool`, `number`, `string`, `symbol`.

Thus, if you will try this:

```
var strictTypeHeaders: { [key: string]: string } = {}; // non-primitive type
var header: object = {};
header = strictTypeHeaders; // its OK
strictTypeHeaders = header; // causes error "Type 'object' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: string }`"
```

you will get the compile error on the last line. This happens because `{ [key: string]: string }` type is more specific than `object` type. There is no any error on `header = strictTypeHeaders` since both types are non-primitive and `object` is more common type than `{ [key: string]: string }`

Comment: Please don't say "*Any object (primitive, non-primitive, null and etc)*" but "any *value*". A primitive is not an object.

Comment: Good answer. Would be great to add the reference urls (if any).

Comment: In TS if a function parameter is of type: `{ }`, I cannot call that function with a value of `null`..  Seems to contradict above.

Comment: `Object` and `{}` are not quite the same. Built-in methods have pre-defined enforced types for `Object` but not for `{}`. So `let x: {} = {toString() { return 2 }}` will run, but `let x: Object = {toString() { return 2 }}` will result in an error (because `toString` requires returning a string for `Object` but not for `{}`).

Answer (score 84):

The following example shows how different types of object behave differently:

```js
var o: object;
o = { prop: 0 }; // OK
o = []; // OK
o = 42; // Error
o = "string"; // Error
o = false; // Error
o = null; // Error
o = undefined; // Error

var p: {}; // or Object
p = { prop: 0 }; // OK
p = []; // OK
p = 42; // OK
p = "string"; // OK
p = false; // OK
p = null; // Error
p = undefined; // Error

var q: { [key: string]: any };
q = { prop: 0 }; // OK
q = []; // OK
q = 42; // Error
q = "string"; // Error
q = false; // Error
q = null; // Error
q = undefined; // Error

var r: { [key: string]: string };
r = { prop: 'string' }; // OK
r = { prop: 0 }; // Error
r = []; // Error
r = 42; // Error
r = "string"; // Error
r = false; // Error
r = null; // Error
r = undefined; // Error
```

With that we can tell:

- `{}` which is the same as type `Object` is the least specific. You can assign objects, arrays and primitives to it.
- `object` is more specific and is similar to `{ [key: string]: any }`. You can assign objects and arrays to it, but not primitives.
- `{ [key: string]: string }` is the most specific, that doesn't allow any primitive types, arrays or objects with a non-string value to be assigned to it.

[Link to TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/G4QwTgBA9gXNBGArApgYwC4G4BQUIF4IBvCABzClLgAYIBfTCAeiYgHkBpXAiAbQF1GLdlzyEALACYhrAKJgKYboQBEAZ3RgAlgDsA5ipkR5i5RABmIADZrkRk1CViIOgK5Wr9hY7OudAE2RzXWR-L1NsUEg2ODYkNCxsNh4SckoaeiNOJJ4BLK5kiWlmVmzCiHVNXQN8nMJLGzsSkTqXd09mhyVyv0DgnVDwn0jwMjgiBmxSFLIKKghaBmbs6cI85a5ViClarcrtfUMNqZ4G212eNw8hpS3eoJCwzu8lEcgAR3G+AGtkAE84BoDnp+HAQDo-plsO8Zml5otajC1oJjkjtsVhF1oTx9tUjpiXtj6tZzs9TGirh0CeSePd+oMycMohAwF9eL8ARAgdVQVyqvooZBCKk5nAAOTc-RizLHIXEWbpBYy6k+OXrFVKOU7RmanGSmo67Bys5NDVGy7tG7mwh0x43IA)

Comment: note that `console.log(typeof o)` is 'object'  in all these cases