# how to fix 'Property 'dials' does not exist on type 'Object' in typeScript

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, arraylist, angular7

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DashboardService } from 'src/app/provider/dashboard.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  revenueTargetProgress: Object;
  dials: object;   
  Guage = this.TotalRevenue;

  constructor(private api: DashboardService) { 

    this.revenueTargetProgress = {
  chart: {
    caption: "Revenue Target Progress",
    lowerLimit: "0",
    upperLimit: "100000000",
    showValue: "1",
    numberPrefix: "₹ ",
    theme: "fusion",
    showToolTip: "0"
  },
  // Chart Data
  colorRange: {
    color: [
      {
        minValue: "0",
        maxValue: "30000000",
        code: "#F2726F"
      },
      {
        minValue: "30000000",
        maxValue: "80000000",
        code: "#FFC533"
      },
      {
        minValue: "80000000",
        maxValue: "1000000000",
        code: "#62B58F"
      }
    ]
  },
  dials: {
    dial: [
      {
        value: "4800000"
      }
    ]
  }

}; 


  }

  ngOnInit() {
    debugger;
    this.api.getAllRevenueTarget().subscribe(res => {
      this.TopCustomers = res;      
      this.customerBarChart.data = this.TopCustomers;
      this.TotalRevenue = this.TopCustomers.map(x => x.value).reduce((a, value) => a + value, 0);
      let dials: any;
      var Value = this.revenueTargetProgress.dials.dial[0].value = this.TotalRevenue;
      //Value.dial[0].value = this.TotalRevenue;      
    });



  }



}
```

Property 'dials' does not exist on type 'Object'  getting this error, i'm new to Angular 7 typescript. i want to clear this error that's it. i tried by declaring dials: any;   dials: Array;   dials: any[] = [];   dials: any=[];

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the type of the `revenueTargetProgress` property.

`Object` is the type of the the `Object` javascript prototype. It hasn't much meaning on its own, besides being preceded by `extends`. You can learn more about the differences between `any`, `Object`, `object` and `{}` in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961203/any-vs-object#targetText=All%20types%20in%20TypeScript%20are,type%20called%20the%20Any%20type.&targetText=The%20Any%20type%20is%20the,static%20constraints%20on%20their%20values.) or [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49464634/difference-between-object-and-in-typescript).

If you know the type of `revenueTargetProgress`, you can assign it in place of `Object`. If you don't know it and you like some degree of risk, you can assign `any`.

Comment: actually 'revenueTargetProgress' is Json i get it from 'fusionCharts' i can't make changes to it

Comment: You don't have to make changes to it. You have to assign a type to it