# Typescript function define multiple return type

Tags: typescript

Hey I am new to typescript and I have function which either returns an object or an array

```
const workspace = (workspace: string)  => {
```

How Can I define a return type for the same

```
const workspace = (workspace:string): Array | Object => {
```

is giving following error

```
Generic type 'Array<T>'
```

I don't know in advance the structure of the Array and also I am not sure if this is `Array | Object` or not.

Comment: It returns an array of _what_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array` is not a type but type constructor, `Array<SomeType>` is a type, that is why you cannot say something returns type constructor, it needs to return specific type. If your function is polymorphic and can work with any array you can pass type generic argument to `Array` type constructor. Consider following code:

```
const workspace = <T>(workspace:string): Array<T> | Object => { ...
```

Thanks to that you return of `workspace` will have specific type applied.

You can also just pass `unknown` or `any` if elements are not needed to be known:

```
const workspace = (workspace:string): Array<any> | Object => { ...
```

One more explanation about type constructors. Every type definition which is requiring another type as argument is a type constructor, you can think about that as function on types. Consider example:

```
type AConstructor<T> = {a: T} // type constructor
type A = AConstructor<string> // evaluates to type {a: string}
```

Comment: Also, `Object` is [unlikely to be what is meant here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#number-string-boolean-symbol-and-object); probably `object` should be used.  Of course, `Array<any> | object` isn't much better than `object`, since an array is an object too.  ‍♂️  It depends on the use case, which is lacking in the question.

Comment: Thanks @jcalz, In my answer I have focued on Array issue as that was the question about.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Array type is generic, you need to say array of what you're returning.

```
const workspace = (workspace:string): Array<SomeType> | Object => { }
```

If you really don't know the type of the elements in the array, you need to use `unknown`.

```
const workspace = (workspace:string): Array<unknown> | Object => { }
```

Also check this answer to find the difference between Object and object:
[Difference between 'object' and {} in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49464634/difference-between-object-and-in-typescript)

You probably wanted `object`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Array<String>;
```

if type cant be determined use `<any>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `any` if you don't know what type of data it will return.

```
const workspace = (workspace:string): Array<any> | Object => {}
```

-----------------Extra Note------------------

You can use typescript's way to define a function. 
Please refer following code:

```
workspace(workspace: string): Array<any> | object {
                //your code here
                // your code here
              }
```