# Typescript generic type parameters: T vs T extends {}

Tags: typescript, generic-type-parameters

Is there functionally any difference between the two generic type parameters below?.

```ts
function funcA<T>() { }
function funcB<T extends {}>() {}
```

I have seen them both used and am confused as to the differences?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Note: I'll assume you're using a version of TypeScript 3.5 or later; in TypeScript 3.5 a change was made so that [generic type parameters are implicitly constrained by `unknown` instead of the empty object type `{}`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#generic-type-parameters-are-implicitly-constrained-to-unknown), and some minor details about the difference between `funcA()` and `funcB()` changed.  I don't want to make a long post even longer by talking about how things used to be in TS3.4 and below.

---

If you don't explicitly [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) a generic type parameter via `extends XXX`, then it will implicitly be constrained by [`unknown`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type), the "top type" to which all types are assignable.  So in practice that means the `T` in `funcA<T>()` could be absolutely any type you want.

On the other hand, the empty object type `{}`, is a type to which *nearly* all types are assignable, ***except* for `null` and `undefined`**, when you have enabled the [`--strictNullChecks` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#--strictnullchecks) (which you should).  Even primitive types like `string` and `number` are assignable to `{}`.

So compare:

```
function funcA<T>() { }
funcA<undefined>(); // okay
funcA<null>(); // okay
funcA<string>(); // okay
funcA<{ a: string }>(); // okay
```

with

```
function funcB<T extends {}>() { }
funcB<undefined>(); // error
funcB<null>(); // error
funcB<string>(); // okay
funcB<{ a: string }>(); // okay
```

The only difference is that `T extends {}` forbids `null` and `undefined`.

---

It might be a little confusing that `{}`, a so-called "object" type, would accept primitives like `string` and `number`.  It helps to think of such curly-brace-surrounded types like `{}` and `{a: string}` as well as all `interface` types not necessarily as "true" object types, but as types of values where you can index into them as if they were objects without getting runtime errors.  Primitives except for `null` and `undefined` are "object-like" in that you can treat them as if they were [wrapped with their object equivalents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive#Primitive_wrapper_objects_in_JavaScript):

```
const s: string = "";
s.toUpperCase(); // okay
```

And therefore even primitives like `string` are assignable to curly-brace-surrounded types as long as the members of those types match:

```
const x: { length: number } = s; // okay
```

If you really need to express a type that only accepts "true", i.e., *non-primitive* objects, you can use the [`object`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html#object-type):

```
const y: object & { length: number } = s; // error
const z: object & { length: number } = { length: 10 }; // okay
```

But I (seriously) digress.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABKSBBAPAFQHwAoCUiA3ogL4BQKEG4AJgKbAxj2174DciA9N4nAGsAhgE9K4aujAgANjPZde-YWKoYAzlABOzAOYKefQaPFp0JIQC5EmnWF1kDS42NPR4SKgCEsiegA8oejBadWJSdmIyNx86RmZWJz56LS04LRipWXkCRWTU9MzbPSTlE29zRCsbbT1HXMMy1wgETUQwa2k5RABeduyOchawNpBrOKYWWl7ECYTaQeG29Wti+xmAIg3F1qh+axIZYN0oAAtOkABbACMUshnD47PrAEYABjJB8jAAOig4ADKtXsDSUKTSWkGID+gOBulB+QhXHI6hhAFUAA4YlIAYSE6noCKaKJ+R3sZy+Sz2-gOiDJJ3O-Rud1IM3UeSaiHIQ12iBE1jg1wAVvRoIgAGRRenPJm3LT3PrsxrgwpUxAALwFwtFe0lj3JjOkzPlrL6+oZrw+pA5LnIQA)

Answer (score 6):

Yes. In `funcB`, T must extend `{}` which means pretty much anything except [`null` and `undefined`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49464634/difference-between-object-and-in-typescript). T can be a primitive though.

Answer (score 0):

The following is to indicate a generic param, in the following case is used to indicate the type param that the function can accept:

```
function funcA<T>(t: T) { }
```

you can use it to indicate what type the function returns as follows:

```
function funcA<T>(t:T):T {}
```

On the other hand `T extends Something` is indicate that the function can accept any parameter that extends `Something`. Let's say we have an interface `Person` and some other interfaces which implements `Person` like `Teacher`, `Student` we can write a function:

```
function funcA<T extends Person>(t: T)
```

we can only call `funcA` with a parameter that extends T.