# What type name does Typescript use for {}?

Tags: typescript

What type name does Typescript use to denote a variable in the form of "{}"?

This is probably super obvious to most, but I'm new to Typescript and I'm converting some Javascript, and this basic question is surprisingly difficult to google. All the other basic types are well documented, but I can't find anything for the basic hash type. I'm not sure if it's "object" or "Object" or "Map" or "any".

Answer (score 3):

For all intents and purposes<sup>*</sup> the empty object type (`{}`) is interchangeable with the `Object` type. All values that have properties (i.e. aren't `null` or `undefined`) can be assigned to `Object` or `{}`.

The `object` type on the other hand is for all non-[primitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive) values, and thus isn't interchangeable with `Object` or `{}`.

The `Map<KeyType, ValueType>` type specifically denotes a [Map object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

And finally `any` literally means *any* value: it can be a primitive or not, null, or undefined and anything I neglected to list here.

See [Difference between 'object' ,{} and Object in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49464634/difference-between-object-and-object-in-typescript) for more.

Even though they exist in TypeScript, you most likely don't actually want to use `{}` or `Object` in your code, there's a specific [eslint rule](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/ban-types.md) for typescript that gives more details about this:

When you type a value as `{}`, it'll warn you with: don't use `{}` as a type. `{}` actually means "any non-nullish value".

- If you want a type meaning "any object", you probably want `Record<string, unknown>` instead.
- If you want a type meaning "any value", you probably want `unknown` instead.
- If you want a type meaning "empty object", you probably want `Record<string, never>` instead.

And when using `Object`: don't use `Object` as a type. The `Object` type actually means "any non-nullish value", so it is marginally better than `unknown`.

- If you want a type meaning "any object", you probably want `Record<string, unknown>` instead.
- If you want a type meaning "any value", you probably want `unknown` instead.

---

<sup>*</sup> The empty object type and the `Object` type actually differ in their compile time semantics: the built-in methods (like `.toString()`) aren't type-checked for `{}` but are checked for `Object`

Answer (score 1):

`{}` is an object literal. Object literals in TypeScript can define nearly any kind of object. An *empty* object literal as in your example (literally `{}`) is equivalent to type `Object`. But an object literal with properties in it defines a possibly-anonymous type for an object with those properties, not just `Object`. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49464634/difference-between-object-and-object-in-typescript) that Emma Koskinen linked in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68047399/157247) for more about `{}`, `Object`, and `object`.)

One of the keys to understanding TypeScript's type system is that it's *structural* (based on the shape of things), not *nominal* (based on the names of things). For example:

```typescript
interface Example {
    a: number;
    b: string;
}
function fn(x: Example) {
    console.log(x.a, x.b);
}

const obj = {a: 42, b: "Life, the Universe, and Everything"};
fn(obj); // <=== No error here
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIA84FsAOAbFAbwChkzk4AuZEAVywCNoBuU8h6gZzClAHNWAX2IxaIBGGAB7EMhggAFOmoZs+CAEpkJcsgQzOUggDo8UvkuNwANMnTGGGocWL6Q3ZFIYArZAF5tKmQAFgAmWw5kACIAGWAYCFswAAsUAFUQYAA3aE5EihAAEzQcqABPFP4owVZ5BS9vJ2QAembkAB4-LuQAOSlkaCgpKGRUqAhiIA)

Nothing says that `obj` is of type `Example`, but that's fine, because it's assignment-compatible with `Example`, so passing it to `fn` is perfectly fine.

In fact, we can go even further, and explicitly say that `obj` is a different type:

```typescript
interface Example {
    a: number;
    b: string;
}
function fn(x: Example) {
    console.log(x.a, x.b);
}

interface AnotherExample {
    a: number;
    b: string;
    c: boolean;
}

const obj: AnotherExample = {a: 42, b: "Life, the Universe, and Everything", c: true};
fn(obj); // <=== No error here
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIA84FsAOAbFAbwChkzk4AuZEAVywCNoBuU8h6gZzClAHNWAX2IxaIBGGAB7EMhggAFOmoZs+CAEpkJcsgQzOUggDo8UvkuNwANMnTGGGocWKhIsRCgCCIKWAAW0Kq4BNpsZFQ09ExQrLocyNy8IALhetQMUkYQcCDOxPog3MhSDABW1D5+gVDB6sgAvNqRACwATLYJAEQAMsAwELYBKACqIMAAbtCcgxQgACZoU1AAngH8XbYI1Dy0EIKs8gqlZU7IAPTnyAA8DXfIAHJSyNBQUlDINRDEQA)

There, we've *explicitly* said that `obj` is of type `AnotherExample`, which is (slightly) different from `Example`. But it's still just fine to pass it to `fn`, because all that `fn` requires is that the object have `Example`'s shape (`a: number; b: string;`), and `obj` does. It has an excess property `c`, but that doesn't matter to `fn`. `fn` has said it only care about `a` and `b`.