# Why 1 extends {} is true?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a TypeScript question when I wrote TS conditional types, like following code:

```js
type T = 1 extends {} ? true : false;
```

Why T returns true?

Comment: `Number` extends `Object`

Comment: and any primitive type (number, string, boolean) has a corresponding Class (Number, String, Boolean). The type of a var like that gets converted by the engine according to the operation you need to do and it's often made with a so called transient object that gets destroyed after the operation is done. So even if the literal `1` is supposed to be `number`, it gets threated as `Number` in that case.

Comment: Hmm, you're changing the scope of your question after you've asked it.  Has it stabilized yet?

Comment: I've reverted the question to its original form. You can ask about the second part in a different question. It's unfair to the comments and the answer.

Comment: The type `{}` means "anything which can be indexed into like an object" and, as such, only prohibits `null` and `undefined` (assuming `--strictNullChecks`).  You could write `(1).toFixed` so `1` is indexable.

Comment: Related: [Difference between 'object' ,{} and Object in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49464634/difference-between-object-and-object-in-typescript)

Comment: @DiegoDeVita: Not *every* primitive type, only the ones you mentioned and bigint (not undefined, null or symbols).

Comment: @FelixKling why not symbols?

Comment: [Here is the OP's new/related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71799555/why-1-extends-key-string-never-is-false), for those who wanted to weigh in.

Comment: @FelixKling ok I went too far after reading again yesterday some pages from Javascript: the definitive guide (6th edition if I'm not mistaken) ... and it's quite old now ;)

Comment: @jcalz: Seems like I was wrong about symbols! They do have an object wrapper. Somehow I thought they didn't but of course it must somehow be possible to access their description... I got carried away :D

Answer (score 1):

Because `<number> extends <Object>` evaluates to `true`.

Comment: But *why* does it do that? A number is a primitive, not an object.