# Why 1 extends {[Key: string]: never} is false

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am very confusing about this, why `1 extends {[Key: string]: never}` is false. For example:

```js
type T = 1 extends {[Key: string]: never} ? true : false;
```

Why T returns false.

Comment: The type `{[key: string]: never}` means "something which can be indexed into like an object, except any known property must be of the impossible `never` type", or more tersely as "objectlike with no known properties".  This eliminates just about everything except the empty interface `{}`.  Certainly the type `1` which has all the known properties of `Number` (e.g., `"toFixed"`) is not assignable to that type, since `(1).toFixed` is of type `(fractionDigits?: number) => string` which is not `never`.  Can you explain why you expect `1 extends {[key: string]: never}` to be `true`?

Comment: Also note, the syntax `{[key: string]: XXX}` is a string [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures).  `key` is a dummy key name and not a type name, so conventionally you would write it in lowerPascalCase (object keys are not typically UpperPascalCase) as `k` or `key` and not `K` or `Key`.

Comment: @jcalz Because `1 extends {} returns true`, so I am confused.

Comment: I understand *that* you are confused but I still don't understand *why*.  Why do you expect `{}` and `{[key: string]: never}` to act the same? They are different types. `{}` means "I don't know of any properties" while `{[key: string]: never}` means "there *cannot* be any properties".  (And note, in my first comment, I misspoke when I wrote "objectlike with no known properties"; I should have said "objectlike which prohibits known properties" or something)

Comment: @jcalz Because from my understanding, I think they all object types, so I think these two maybe all return true.

Comment: I'm happy to write up an answer explaining why `1` is not assignable to `{[k: string]: never}`, but I'm not sure how `{}` fits into it unless that's written into the question itself.  There might be a language barrier; you are speaking in the present tense with "I think they are all object types so I think these two maybe all return true"; do you *still* think that?  Or has my explanation with `(1).toFixed` not being of type `never` changed that?  I want to be sure that if I write up an answer, it will address your issue.

Comment: @jcalz Thank you, I understand your explanation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243738/discussion-between-chenlee-and-jcalz).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A type of the form `{[key: string]: XXX}` has a `string` [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures). A value of such a type may have any number (including zero) of string-keyed members (members are properties, which include methods, and include inherited properties); and any string-keyed members that it does have must be of type `XXX`:

```
let dict: { [key: string]: string };
dict = { a: "hello", b: "goodbye" }; // okay
dict = { a: "hello", b: 123 }; // error!
// ----------------> ~ 
// Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
dict = {} // okay
```

[The `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type) is TypeScript's [*bottom type*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom_type); there are *no* values of type `never`.  It is to types what the empty set is to sets.  No matter what value you have, it will *not* be of type `never`.  You should not be able to observe a value of type `never`.

Putting those together, a value of type `{[key: string]: never}` may have any number of string-keyed members (including zero), and any string-keyed members that it does have must be of type `never`.  But since no value is of type `never`, it means that a value of type `{[key: string]: never}` must have *exactly* zero string-keyed members:

```
let neverDict: { [key: string]: never };
neverDict = { a: "hello", b: "goodbye" }; // error!
// ---------> ~  -------> ~
// Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.

dict = {} // okay
```

Or at least any string-keyed members that are present must be expected to be unobservable:

```
function error(): never { throw new Error(); }
function special() {
  dict = { a: error() } // okay
}
```

Here we assign a value of type `{a: never}` to `dict`, which is fine, but note that if you ever tried to run the program to look at such a value it would be unobservable because an error will be thrown.

So, in order to be assignable to `{[key: string]: never}`, a type must have no string-keyed members.

---

On the other hand we have the type `1`.  This is a numeric [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) which is a subtype of `number`.  Every value of type `1` is also a value of type `number`.  Furthermore, `number` is a subtype of `Number`, the interface for the [wrapper object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive#primitive_wrapper_objects_in_javascript) that `number` values are given when you index into them like objects.

Here's [the definition of the `Number` interface](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/3b2fa50a14a380e25639cea579e33d9b452d63ed/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L542-L569) from the TypeScript standard library:

```
interface Number {
    toString(radix?: number): string;
    toFixed(fractionDigits?: number): string;
    toExponential(fractionDigits?: number): string;
    toPrecision(precision?: number): string;
    valueOf(): number;
}
```

Do note that all primitives in JavaScript except `null` and `undefined` have such wrapper objects, and so these primitives can be assigned to interfaces and are thus "object-like" in their treatment by TypeScript.

So, `1` is a subtype of `number`, which is a subtype of `Number`, which has some known members as shown above:

```
let one: 1 = 1;
let prim: number = 1;
let intf: Number = prim;

(1).toFixed // (method) Number.toFixed(fractionDigits?: number | undefined): string
```

---

And so now we can see that `1` should not be assignable to `{[key: string]: never}`.  The former has several members with keys like `"toFixed"` and `"toExponential"`, and these members have values of function types.  Functions are actual values which are not assignable to `never`.  So this is an error:

```
neverDict = one; // error!
// Type 'number' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: never; }'.
```

And therefore `1 extends {[key: string]: never}` is false, and so the [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) you wrote takes the false branch:

```
type T = 1 extends { [key: string]: never } ? true : false;
// type T = false
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2#code/FAGwpgLgBAJglgYwgLigbygbQNZgJ6oDOEATnAHYDmAukaRZVAL4Dcw8SUAvOlAIaoARAAswIEAHtBAGigAjIZQkSYcvGEHMWUAPQ6oE7HzztE0HhgFQRYyTPmoAjACYAzFt36wJEhJIBCYD0oAFow8IjIkIA+KAA-KCD9ABU8AAcwKABycgBXAFs5byyoOEIocgloPkJCOEpyPjlwKAgJVvTMrOIyKiyAOlNOCyZPAyMTYCnwaHIwADdvABEzVAwcfDpemlQ5xZItYD3ls25eKxtxKVkFayUVNQ0PYO9fAKTQqLDYhM-In4+qQy2R6DBKZQqVX4tXqjWamTaHWBOQWxUGQ3M6FGwUMximADNcuQkHAJOQoK8-AAKACUu1RBwwEGEvgA7hUwOyAKI+ak07RMYCE4kQUnkwgZBBwPggWnoYBQWCnCz8VCUkhy7H6XEmQXTSAGOZOM6ONgzKBpMj5XYFIoHHim0AGigQfGoABytu8Z0tcHybGAVMcNP6bQAYnAAB5gGBjKn5SDCFQ0qCewreUMSCPRmBU-EkPgkskrShwCCEAD8NvTBwAPlAiTAwPiKDG6VBQVQpkcGSthoawNoXrz3sEgV08jXweVKtUYQ0mi1ERBOtl1rgCB36FRaBz9gKBt2V8DkiaKZGIGByDByuvNlvtrvjgdRhXWiRcplUPiZYRBx9j0yU8eB-EA-yAA)

Answer (score 1):

I was confused with a same phenomenon:

```js
type test1 = 1 extends {} ? true : false // true
```

So, I guess, when compare original type with object, there is an **implicit type conversion** happend just like below code:

```js
type test2 = {
  [key in keyof 1]: 1[key]
}
/**
  type test2 = {
    toString: (radix?: number | undefined) => string;
    toFixed: (fractionDigits?: number | undefined) => string;
    toExponential: (fractionDigits?: number | undefined) => string;
    toPrecision: (precision?: number | undefined) => string;
    valueOf: () => number;
    toLocaleString: (locales?: string | ... 1 more ... | undefined, options?: Intl.NumberFormatOptions | undefined) => string;
  }
 */
```

it is confilcted with `{[Key: string]: never}`

Comment: From MDN on 'extends': An expression that evaluates to a constructor function (including a class) or null. When you extends an {} you'll receive a class. The logic is '1' aka Number extends {} Object, which will return Number class - that is what you see printed as keys, the Number object class eg notice toFixed() Number method. You don't end up with the above issues, which is related to 'never'. The above is more TS specific, your query is more JS specific.

Comment: @alanionita I understand your view, `implicit type conversion` just is a nomenclature for describing the internal processes happened in the TypeScript's `extends` grammer in my understanding. It migth be a comparison between `Number` and `Object` in fact

Comment: No conversion here, just part of JS. JS has both primitives and Object classes to match and the interpreter 'resolves' them both the same. So the logic is translated to '1' as Number extends {} as  Object which of course is true because Number object extends the Object base class. number (primitive) is a subclass of Number.

It is indeed the comparison you mentioned, but it's not done by TS, it's standard JS. Here's a bit of an explanation from MDN on string and String https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#string_primitives_and_string_objects

Comment: TLDR: primitives have corresponding classes, primitives are subclasses of type class, all classes are subclasses of Object class, JS interprets primitives as type classes.

Comment: @alanionita Hmm, In my mind, TS's `extends` extended JS's `extends`, there might be something happened in TS'complier. So I think your view might be inaccurate