# Typescript and destructured variables not recognising props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-typescript

I have a function that returns `data`. The object that gets returned contains headerMenu, page, content and footer. These are all returned as objects of which all of this is defined in DataProps

With the line
`const { headerMenu, page: { content }, footer }: DataProps = data`
Its throwing an error saying that **Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'DataProps': headerMenu, page, content, footer**

But we can see the props are defined here? What am I missing here or can we not use destructuring in TS

Full component code below

````
type IndexProps = {
  postData: object,
  preview: boolean,
}

type PreviewSubscriptionProps = {
  data: object,
}

type DataProps = {
  headerMenu: object,
  page: object,
  content: object,
  footer: object,
}

export default function Index({ postData, preview } : IndexProps) {
  const router = useRouter();
  
  const {data} : PreviewSubscriptionProps = usePreviewSubscription(HomepageGroq, {
    initialData: postData,
    enabled: preview || router.query.preview !== undefined,
  });

  const { headerMenu, page: { content }, footer }: DataProps = data

  return (
    <>
      <SiteHeader headerMenu={headerMenu} />

      <Content content={content} />

      <SiteFooter footer={footer} />
    </>
  );
}```
````

Comment: You should type `PreviewSubscriptionProps` as `type PreviewSubscriptionProps = { data: DataProps }`, and properly type the `DataProps` properties as well. Avoid using `object`.

Answer (score 1):

PreviewSubscriptionProps has a key data of `object` type.

```
type PreviewSubscriptionProps = {
  data: object,
}
```

In TS, `object` type is used to represent just a non primitive type. It is not a `string`,`number`,`boolean` etc. But, it is not guaranteed to have any key.

[A min repro example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBADg9gzmAIgQzMgXBGAjAViAY0gF4IBvAWACgJaJkJMBGagX2uoJgDsFyIAJqgasIpWAhRoA3NSA)

```
 const {data} : PreviewSubscriptionProps = ...
 const { headerMenu, page: { content }, footer }: DataProps = data
```

In the above statement you try to destructure the data key. But data is just of `object` type. Hence you get the error.

You can use `any` instead of `object` if you are not sure about the keys. [Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49464634/difference-between-object-and-object-in-typescript)

Further, you will also face an issue here:

```
const { headerMenu, page: { content }, footer }: DataProps = data
```

The above means you are [trying](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOAFATgezAZygXigbwFgAoKKACwjgBMIUBZCAOwFcAuKNAIwCsIBjYABoSZMHADmEDtz6CRpKPzRNgzYDN4DhoqADM0aNSk1ydxAL4ldyppmAEKVWg2YshUcVI+21qqB4GRnRQFhzwiKgY2HjUCHBAA) to extract **content** key from **page**. You would want to extract like this:

```
const { headerMenu, page, content , footer }: DataProps = data
```

Comment: Not sure that last part will work as content is a child of page. I think this might be where I'm getting my head mixed up with typescript.

Comment: If `content` is a child of `page`. Shouldn't you use this ? 
type DataProps = {
  headerMenu: object,
  page: {
  content: object
...otherproperties},
  footer: object,
}

Comment: if I add page: {content: object} content is not accessible in the rest of my script. Windering if you can't destructure to this second level

Answer (score 0):

PreviewSubscriptionProps type does not all the keys of DataProps type fix that and you are destructuring like this `const { headerMenu, page: { content }, footer }: DataProps = data` but your DataProps type has been defined like

```
type DataProps = {
  headerMenu: object,
  page: object,
  content: object,
  footer: object,
}
```

content is not in an page. Fix this also. Either destructure like this
`const { headerMenu, page, content, footer }: DataProps = data` or modify DataProps type.

Comment: As mentioned on the other answer. "Not sure that will work as content is a child of page. I think this might be where I'm getting my head mixed up with typescript"

Comment: If content is child of page then DataProps will be like `type DataProps = {headerMenu : object,  page : { content : object}, footer : object}`