# How can I write a typeguard for an interface that checks attribute types?

Tags: typescript, typeguards

I have a TypeScript project and have defined a custom interface

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
}
```

I would like to create a type guard for this interface that only returns `true` if a value adheres to that interface.  Specifically that it is...

1. An Object
2. with a `name` property
3. where the value of `name` is of type `string`

I am able to accomplish 1 and 2 as follows:

```js
const isPerson = (value: unknown): value is Person => (
  value instanceof Object
  && 'name' in value
)
```

However if I try to check the type of `value.name`...

```js
const isPerson = (value: unknown): value is Person => (
  value instanceof Object
  && 'name' in value
  && typeof value.name === 'string'
)
```

I receive the following error, highlighting `.name`

```
Property 'name' does not exist on type 'never'.ts(2339)
```

How can I create a type guard that ensures not only that a property exists but ALSO that the property is of a certain type?

Answer (score 1):

- You need to use a *type-assertion* (i.e. `as`) to allow you to *hypothetically test* object properties in TypeScript.

  - In my own personal coding style, I always name this local `whatIf` to make it obvious it's not-real.
- Test each property with the `typeof` operator, which is safe to use with first-level maybe-undefined properties.

  - Don't forget that `var x = null; typeof x === 'object'`, so you also need to check for `x !== null` too.
- You don't need to use the `in` operator - and TypeScript cannot use `in` to determine property-types, only property-is-not-`undefined`.

Something like this:

```js
const isPerson = (value: unknown): value is Person {

    const whatIf = value as Person;
    return (
        ( typeof whatIf === 'object' && whatIf !== null )
        &&
        ( typeof whatIf.name === 'string' )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you have generic approach:

```js
interface Person {
    name: string
}


const hasProperty = <Obj, Prop extends string>(obj: Obj, prop: Prop)
    : obj is Obj & Record<Prop, unknown> =>
    Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop);

const isPerson = (obj: unknown): obj is Person =>
    hasProperty(obj, 'name') && typeof obj.name === 'string'
```

`hasProperty` is a generic utility type for checking/typeguarding properties in objects

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mZ4QKw)

Comment: I upvoted for the clever use of `Record<Prop,unknown>` in an intersection - I'll try to use this approach in future as it's more succinct than my approach, but because it uses `hasOwnProperty` it won't work with inherited prototype members - is there a reason for using `hasOwnProperty` instead of the `in` operator?

Comment: This is exactly the reason why I have used `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call`. See [this](https://v8.dev/features/object-has-own). If you want to check prototype you can use `prop in object` or `object.hasOwnProperty`. I'm not sure, please test it in runtime. My main focus is on types rather than runtime behaviour, I should have pointed that

Answer (score 0):

`instanceof Object` should probably be avoided. For example the below code enters the `else` clause, even though the compiler infers `o` as `never` in that clause. Use `typeof v === 'object'` instead. [Here's a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49464634/difference-between-object-and-object-in-typescript/49465172) talking about the difference between `Object` (which is inferred from `instanceof`) and `object` (which is inferred from `typeof`).

```
interface Person {
    name: string
}

const o: Object = "a"

if (o instanceof Object) {
    console.log(o, "is Object")
} else {
    console.log(o, "is not Object")
}
```

I always try to avoid type assertions, so this is how I would solve it.

```
const hasName = <T extends {}>(value: T): value is T & {name: unknown} => "name" in value

const isPerson = (value: unknown): value is Person => (
  typeof value === 'object'
  && value !== null
  && hasName(value)
  && typeof value.name === 'string'
)
```