# Why {} (object) does not allow 'null' and 'undefined'?

Tags: typescript, typescript-utility

Looking at the utility type 'NonNullable' of the type script, it is implemented as this.

```
/**
 * Exclude null and undefined from T
 */
type NonNullable = T & {}; 


type Object1 = {};    
type Object2 = object;

const testObj1: Object1 = {
    test: 'test',
}; // ok
const testObj2: Object2 = {
    test: 'test',
}; // ok

const testStr1: Object1 = ''; // ok
const testStr2: Object2 = ''; // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'object'.ts(2322)
```

{} Instead, what happens inside the type script when extends the 'object'?

Why does the type checker detect differently as in the example above?

I'd appreciate it if you could answer my questions, thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please [edit] your post to [ask exactly one question, not multiple](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/39224/511366).  Otherwise it risks being closed as needing focus.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49464634/difference-between-object-and-object-in-typescript

Comment: @JayBuckman thank you! When I tried to write in the past, they recommended a similar article, but this time I didn't have it, so I couldn't find it properly. It was a good reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An object literal type, written as curly braces containing zero or more property declarations, is an assertion that the value of that type

1. Can have properties accessed at runtime, and
2. Has the specified properties, with the specified types.

Now, the empty object literal type `{}` in particular has no specified properties, so only (1) is in play. That is, `{}` is the type of anything that can have properties accessed at runtime. This includes object literals (naturally), but it also includes strings, numbers, and Booleans. That is, *all* of the following are `undefined` at runtime, not a runtime error:

- `"example".foo`
- `(3).foo` (Requires extra parentheses if you're using a numerical literal, for syntax purposes)
- `true.foo`
- `false.foo`

However, `null` and `undefined` are unique in that we can't even *try* to access properties on them. `null.foo` and `undefined.foo` are runtime errors, not just `undefined`. So `null` and `undefined` cannot be assigned to any object literal, not even `{}`, since they don't satisfy condition (1) above.

`object`, on the other hand, is defined to be the type of all non-primitive things in Javascript. Javascript [defines](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive) seven primitive types

- `string`
- `number`
- `bigint`
- `boolean`
- `undefined`
- `symbol`
- `null`

And Typescript defines `object` to be: every value which is not one of these seven things.

Typescript also defines `Object` with a capital "O". This is the type of all Javascript values that satisfy the interface defined by [the `Object` type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object).

Generally, that's going to be very similar to `{}`, as any object that is not `null` or `undefined` in Typescript is going to (directly or indirectly) have `Object` as a prototype and hence will inherit all of the built-in `Object` properties. But we can break that. For instance, `Object` defines `toString(): string`, so `{ toString: function() { return 7; } }` is a value which is not of type `Object`, since its `toString` is incompatible with that of `Object`. Though that value *is* of type `{}` (since it can have its properties accessed) and of type `object` (since it is not a primitive value).

Most Typescript style guides recommend avoiding these types, as they cause confusion and are honestly seldom what you want. I mean, when do you *actually* mean "I want this function to accept any value, anything at all, but I specifically forbid `null` and `undefined`"? I recommend the following guidelines.

- If you want the typechecker to take a hike, use `any`. This will basically disable typechecking on that particular variable.
- If you truly know nothing about the value and want to be forced to introspect (with `typeof`, for instance) before doing anything, use `unknown`. `unknown` is the top of the Typescript type hierarchy (excepting `any`), so anything is assignable to it, but it's not assignable to any other type (again, excepting `any`)
- If you want to accept any objects (i.e. anything that came from a `class`, `new`, or an object literal), use `Record<string, unknown>` (or `Record<string, any>` for weaker typing). This type is like `Object` except that it won't accept other primitives like strings and can't be broken with a faulty `toString` or other method. `Record<string, unknown>` is useful for the many Javascript functions that accept an object behaving sort of like a key-value dictionary which were not designed with [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) in mind, as it's usually a mistake to pass a primitive string or number to such functions.