# Setting named object properties, getting "element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"string"' can't be used to index type '{}'"

Tags: typescript

I am trying to modify a poorly typed object at runtime. The properties could be set to anything (any name with any value).

But if I try to do something like this:

```
function setProperty(destination: object, key: string, value: unknown) {
    destination[key] = value
}
```

it's not allowed, and I don't understand why. Is it not perfectly valid that an "object" has named properties?

I mean, what really is the difference between an `object` type and this?:

```
type ActualJsObject = {
    [propertyName: string]: unknown
}
```

Can someone please explain why this code:

```
const myobj: object = {}
const propName: string = "foo"
myobj[propName] = "bar"
```

yields this error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.
```

Comment: `{}` is an _empty_ object. `object` means "not primitive". See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/49464634/3001761